# How to enable submit event in form if validation fails

Tags: jquery, html, forms, form-submit, submit-button

Shopping cart form contains validation form with ajax submit.
If validation fails, alert() box appears and submit is cancelled by `return false`
If validation fails, submit method is not called anymore. Subsequent clicks to button are ignored.

Only first click in green `Lisa ostukorvi` button causes alert box. Subsequent clicks are ignored, submit() event does not fire. This occurs in IE10, FireFox & Chrome. How to fix this?

```
<script>
var request;
$(function() {
$(".browse-addtocart-form").submit(function(event){
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    var $form = $(this);
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    var q = parseInt(this.quantity.value, 10);
    if(isNaN(q) || q === 0){
      alert('Fill quantity');
      $(this.quantity).focus();
      // TODO: Why this causes submit event not to occur on subsequent clicks:
      return false;
      }

    request = $.post('/AddToCart', serializedData );
    return false;
    });
   });
</script>


 <form class='browse-addtocart-form' action="/AddToCartPost" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class='button green small bigrounded' />
</form>
</html>
```

jquery, jquery-ui, ASP .NET MVC2 are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you should use click function like this  $("#submitId").click(function () { /* your code*//}); and give your submit botton an id

Comment: If enter is pressed in form, this code does not run. How to enable submit also via this code if enter is pressed ?

Comment: `$('.browse-addtocart-form').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) { $('input[type="submit"]').trigger('click'); } //13 is enter
});`